# NSTableView reloadData method causes NSProgressIndicator in all rows to update and flicker

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstableview, flicker

*Note: I have searched Stack Overflow for similar problems, and none of the questions I found seem to address this particular problem.*

I've written a small sample app (complete Xcode project with source code available here: http://jollyroger.kicks-ass.org/stackoverflow/FlickeringTableView.zip) that plays all of the sounds in `/System/Library/Sounds/` sequentially and displays the sounds in a window as they are played to show the issue I am seeing. The window in `MainMenu.xib` has a single-column `NSTableView` with one row defined as a cell template with three items in it:

- an `NSTextField` to hold the sound name
- another `NSTextField` to hold the sound details
- a `NSProgressIndicator` to show play progress while the sound is playing

I have subclassed `NSTableCellView` (`SoundsTableCellView.h`) to define each of the items in the cell view so that I can access and set them when the time arises.

I have defined a `MySound` class that encapsulates properties and methods needed to handle the playing of sound files via `AVAudioPlayer` APIs. This class defines a `MySoundDelegate` protocol to allow the app delegate to receive events whenever sounds start or finish playing.

The application delegate adheres to the `NSTableViewDelegate` and `NSTableViewDataSource` protocols to allow it to store the table data as an array of `MySound` objects and update the table with relevant information when needed. It also adheres to the `MySoundDelegate` protocol to receive events when sounds start or finish playing. The delegate also has an `NSTimer` task that periodically calls a `refreshWindow` method to update the progress indicator for the currently playing sound.

The app delegate's `refreshWindow` method displays and resizes the window if needed based on the number of sounds in the list, and updates the stored reference to the associated `NSProgressIndicator` for the sound that is playing.

The app delegate's `tableView: viewForTableColumn` (`NSTableViewDelegate` protocol) method gets called to populate the table cells. In it, I use Apple's standard "Populating a Table View Programmatically" advice to:

1. check the table column identifier to ensure it matches the
   identifier (`sound column`) I set in Interface Builder (Xcode) for the table column,
2. get the corresponding table cell with identifier (`sound cell`) by calling `thisTableView makeViewWithIdentifier`,
3. use the incoming `row` parameter to locate the matching array element
   of the data source (app delegate `sounds` array), then
4. set the string values of `NSTextFields` and set the `maxValue` and `doubleValue` of the `NSProgressIndicator` in the cell to corresponding details of the associated sound object,
5. store a reference to the associated `NSProgressIndicator` control in the associated sound object for later updating

Here's the `viewForTableColumn` method:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)thisTableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)thisTableColumn row:(NSInteger)thisRow
{
    SoundsTableCellView *cellView = nil;

    // get the table column identifier

    NSString *columnID = [thisTableColumn identifier];
    if ([columnID isEqualToString:@"sound column"])
    {
        // get the sound corresponding to the specified row (sounds array index)

        MySound *sound = [sounds objectAtIndex:thisRow];

        // get an existing cell from IB with our hard-coded identifier

        cellView = [thisTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"sound cell" owner:self];

        // display sound name

        [cellView.soundName setStringValue:[sound name]];
        [cellView.soundName setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle];

        // display sound details (source URL)

        NSString *details = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sound sourceURL]];
        [cellView.soundDetails setStringValue:details];
        [cellView.soundDetails setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle];

        // update progress indicators

        switch ([sound state])
        {
            case kMySoundStateQueued:
                break;
            case kMySoundStateReadyToPlay:
                break;
            case kMySoundStatePlaying:
                if (sound.playProgress == nil)
                {
                    sound.playProgress = cellView.playProgress;
                }

                NSTimeInterval duration = [sound duration];
                NSTimeInterval position = [sound position];

                NSLog(@"row %ld: %@ (%f / %f)", (long)thisRow, [sound name], position, duration);
                NSLog(@"         %@: %@", [sound name], sound.playProgress);

                [cellView.playProgress setMaxValue:duration];
                [cellView.playProgress setDoubleValue:position];

                break;
            case kMySoundStatePaused:
                break;
            case kMySoundStateFinishedPlaying:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return cellView;
}
```

And here's the `refreshWindow` method:

```
- (void) refreshWindow
{
    if ([sounds count] > 0)
    {
        // show window if needed

        if ([window isVisible] == false)
        {
            [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        }

        // resize window to fit all sounds in the list if needed

        NSRect frame = [self.window frame];

        int screenHeight = self.window.screen.frame.size.height;

        long maxRows = ((screenHeight - 22) / 82) - 1;
        long displayedRows = ([sounds count] > maxRows ? maxRows : [sounds count]);

        long actualHeight = frame.size.height;
        long desiredHeight = 22 + (82 * displayedRows);
        long delta = desiredHeight - actualHeight;

        if (delta != 0)
        {
            frame.size.height += delta;
            frame.origin.y -= delta;

            [self.window setFrame:frame display:YES];
        }

        // update play position of progress indicator for all sounds in the list

        for (MySound *nextSound in sounds)
        {
            switch ([nextSound state])
            {
                case kMySoundStatePlaying:
                    if (nextSound.playProgress != nil)
                    {
                        [nextSound.playProgress setDoubleValue:[nextSound position]];
                        NSLog(@"         %@: %@ position: %f", [nextSound name], nextSound.playProgress, [nextSound position]);
                    }
                    break;
                case kMySoundStateQueued:
                case kMySoundStateReadyToPlay:
                case kMySoundStatePaused:
                case kMySoundStateFinishedPlaying:
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // hide window

        if ([window isVisible])
        {
            [window orderOut:self];
        }
    }

    // reload window table view

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

During `init`, the application delegate scans the `/System/Library/Sounds/` folder to get a list of AIFF sound files in that folder, and creates a `sounds` array holding sound objects for each of the sounds in that folder. The `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method then starts playing the first sound in the list sequentially.

The problem (which you can see by running the sample project) is that rather than only updating the top table row for the sound that is currently playing, the progress indicators in *all* of the following rows seem to update and flicker as well. The way it displays is somewhat inconsistent (sometimes they all flicker, and sometimes they are all blank as expected); but when they do update and flicker the progress indicators do seem to roughly correspond to the sound that is currently playing. So I am pretty sure the issue must be somehow related to the way I am updating the table; I'm just not sure where the problem is or how to solve it.

Here's a screen shot of what the window looks like to give you an idea:

[Table View Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcwHr.png)

Any ideas or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI: Apple's "Populating a Table View Programmatically" documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html

Comment: `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` "Returns a new or **existing** view with the specified identifier.". All sounds can point to the same control.

Comment: Thanks, @Willeke. I checked, and it appears the progress indicator is indeed _different_ for each row. I've added to the `NSLog` statement in my `makeViewWithIdentifier` method to output the stored reference to the `NSProgressIndicator` for the given sound object. Here's some sample output:  
  
    Basso [<NSProgressIndicator: 0x6280001e0800>]  
    Blow [<NSProgressIndicator: 0x6280001e0800>]  
    Bottle [<NSProgressIndicator: 0x6380001e0d00>]  
    Frog [<NSProgressIndicator: 0x6380001e0700>]

Comment: I take that last comment back. I just noticed that _sometimes_ the progress indicator is the same as you suggested:  `Tink: <NSProgressIndicator: 0x6000001e1f00>` vs `Submarine: <NSProgressIndicator: 0x6000001e1f00>`, and _other_ times it is different: `Sosumi: <NSProgressIndicator: 0x6380001e0700>`. So what is the correct method to obtain a unique cell view for each row?

Comment: You don't need a unique cell. Always set the max and value of the progress indicator in `viewForTableColumn`. Only update the row of the playing sound in `refreshWindow`. Remove the row when you remove a sound.

Comment: Hmm... The `viewForTableColumn` method already does set the value (`setDoubleValue`) and max (`setMaxValue`) of the `NSProgessIndicator`. The `refreshWindow` method already does update the progress indicator of the playing sound. And the `soundFinishedPlaying` method removes the sound object from the data source (`sounds` array) once the sound is finished playing, which automatically removes the row since the `sounds` array is the data source for the table. What do you think I should be doing differently? Can you suggest an actual code change to show me where my code is wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I changed.

`tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` returns "a view to display the specified row and column". The value of the progress bar is always set.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)thisTableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)thisTableColumn row:(NSInteger)thisRow
{
    SoundsTableCellView *cellView = nil;

    // get the table column identifier

    NSString *columnID = [thisTableColumn identifier];
    if ([columnID isEqualToString:@"sound column"])
    {
        // get the sound corresponding to the specified row (sounds array index)

        MySound *sound = [sounds objectAtIndex:thisRow];

        // get an existing cell from IB with our hard-coded identifier

        cellView = [thisTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"sound cell" owner:self];

        // display sound name

        [cellView.soundName setStringValue:[sound name]];

        // display sound details (source URL)

        NSString *details = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sound sourceURL]];
        [cellView.soundDetails setStringValue:details];

        // update progress indicators

        //  [cellView.playProgress setUsesThreadedAnimation:NO];

        NSTimeInterval duration = [sound duration];
        NSTimeInterval position = [sound position];
        [cellView.playProgress setMaxValue:duration];
        [cellView.playProgress setDoubleValue:position];
    }

    // end updates

    //  [thisTableView endUpdates];

    return cellView;
}
```

`refreshWindow` is split into `refreshProgress` and `refreshWindow`. `refreshProgress` refreshes the row of the playing sound and is called on a timer.

```
- (void)refreshProgress
{
    if ([sounds count] > 0)
    {
        [sounds enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MySound *nextSound, NSUInteger rowNr, BOOL *stop)
        {
            switch ([nextSound state])
            {
                case kMySoundStatePlaying:
                    // refresh row
                    [tableView reloadDataForRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:rowNr]
                        columnIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
                    break;
                case kMySoundStateQueued:
                case kMySoundStateReadyToPlay:
                case kMySoundStatePaused:
                case kMySoundStateFinishedPlaying:
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

`refreshWindow` refreshes the size and visibility of the window and is called when the number of sounds changes.

```
- (void) refreshWindow
{
    if ([sounds count] > 0)
    {
        // show window if needed

        if ([window isVisible] == false)
        {
            [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        }

        // resize window to fit all sounds in the list if needed

        ... calculate new window frame

        }
    else
    {
        // hide window

        if ([window isVisible])
        {
            [window orderOut:self];
        }
    }
}
```

When a sound is removed, the row is also removed so the other rows still display the same sound and don't need an update.

```
- (void) soundFinishedPlaying:(MySound *)sound encounteredError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != NULL)
    {
        // display an error dialog box to the user

        [NSApp presentError:error];
    }
    else
    {
        // remove sound from array

        NSLog(@"deleting: [%@|%@]", [sound truncatedID], [sound name]);

        NSUInteger index = [sounds indexOfObject:sound];
        [sounds removeObject:sound];
        [tableView removeRowsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectNone];
    }

    // refresh window

    [self refreshWindow];

    // play the next sound in the queue

    [self play];
}
```

`[tableView reloadData]` isn't called. `sound.playProgress` isn't used.

Comment: Aha. So it seems the answer is not to call `[tableView reloadData]` at all, and to instead call `[tableView reloadDataForRowIndexes...]` instead, along with `[tableView removeRowsAtIndexes...]` to manually remove rows for deleted items in the data source array. I still don't completely understand _why_ `reloadData` causes _all_ progress indicators in the table view to update/flicker, but it's good there is a better way to update them. Thanks for showing me the way! : )

Comment: `makeViewWithIdentifier` reuses the views, when a view isn't used anymore, it is put in a pool of reusable views. The flickering starts when the first sound is removed. When there are 10 views and 9 sounds, every `reloadData` the first 9 views are reused and the 10th view is used first on the next `reloadData`. The views circulate and `viewForTableColumn` didn't set the value of the progress indicator in every view. You can see this happening if you log `sound.name` and the pointer of `cellView.playProgress` in `viewForTableColumn`.

Comment: I see now - got it. Thanks, @Willeke! :)